# Reading file in socket

Tags: python

I am trying to understand  what the following code does?
Can somebody explain to me how does it work?

```
message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
file = message.split()[1]                 
a = open(file[1:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
```

Declares a variable called message which equals a receiving socket who's max number of bytes is 1024.

```
file = message.split()[1]
```

Declares a variable called file which equals message's split value at instance 1.

```
a = open(file[1:])
```

Declares a variable called a, which is equal to a file that is being opened. The file that is being opened is everything after the first character of the variable "file". (if file's value is "abcd" the file being opened is "bcd").